# PHP/Apache error.log doesn't execute new_line characters, why?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, error-handling

For example instead of getting the following

```
post:Array (
  "a" => "b",
  "c" => "d"
)
```

I just get this:

```
post:Array (\n  "a" => "b",\n  "c" => "d"\n)
```

It's really uncomfortable to read this while debugging my code. So if you have any suggestion on why this couldn't work alright, tell me.

I am running it in a Windows7 Putty connected to an Ubuntu virtual server, which runs supposedly  it's default Apache/PHP configuration. (well probably not, but as always nobody in the team remembers to have changed anything)

*edit:* Someone requested the code that writes to the error.log:

```
<?php
error_log(print_r(array("a"=>"b","c"=>"d"),1));
?>
```

The commands to view the error log are:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
sudo vim /var/log/apache2/error.log
sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

In all instances the problem occurs that `\n` is not executed as expected.

Comment: Handling newlines is done by the editor/viewer. Try using a different one.

Comment: Show us the code which is writing to the error log.

Comment: both tried and information added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also faced the same problem, but after spending a few minutes I got a solution.

When you do [`tail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)), use as below:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | sed -e 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

If you want, you can create a file. Give it some name and paste the above command and place that in the `/usr/bin/` folder.

For example

```
vi tailme
```

With the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | sed -ue 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

And put this in `/usr/bin/`. Now you can use `tailme` as a command.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Any idea if there is possibly a terminal setting that auto enables this?

Comment: You can create the same script mentioned above but use this

    tail -f $1 | sed -ue 's/\\n/\n/g' This will let you type something like nameofmyscript /loglocation/logname and it will auto fill the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (e.g. Mac) using Perl might work better:

```
tail -100f /var/log/apache2/error.log | perl -pe 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused when the Apache process can't write into the error_log file, so the syslog writes into the file instead. The syslog messes up the line breaks.

So just do:

```
chmod 777 error.log
```

This should solve your problem. [Source](https://exceptionshub.com/php-error-log-and-newline-chars.html).

Comment: [chmod 777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/) = "sets permissions so that, (U)ser / owner can read, can write and can execute. (G)roup can read, can write and can execute. (O)thers can read, can write and can execute.". How secure is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing the output in the browser, try wrapping your output statement with the `<pre>` tags.

```
<?php
    $post = Array("a" => "b", "c" => "d");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($post);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

outputs to a browser a formatted array:

```
Array
(
    [a] => b
    [c] => d
)
```

Comment: Nice idea. Sadly, it has nothing to do with the browser or the code. I look at the error.log from the shell.

Comment: The `pre` tag is highly relevant for browsers, however not relevant at all on a PHP file based error log

Answer (score 0):

When calling [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log), you can force PHP to log directly instead of passing it to Apache which is the default behavior. To do that, just specify 3 as the second argument and a file path as the third argument.

```php
error_log("error message", 3, $logFileLocation);
```

For more information, check out [PHP error_log documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).